# eclipse (neon) Debugger: "Step into" and "Step Over" are like "Resume"

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I have here a curios problem with my eclipse (neon). I cannot normaly debugging my code. Every time if the program stops at a breakpoint and I want to step into a method by pressing F5 or clicking the "Step Into (F5)" icon the debugger resumes and goes on. Same effect with F6 "Step Over"

Anybody knows whats wrong?!?

Comment: And your Java version is?

Comment: It's JDK8. But just in this second I found the problem: a wrong defined step filter. Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh no! Found it. There was a "Step filter" defined which filters out all of my classes (defined "Step Filter" was "com.*" and all my classes are inside sub packages of "com." ...)